# Linear combination of homogenized composite material

Tags: physical-properties-of-materials, materials-design, materials-engineering, microstructure

My research is on the structural optimization of fibre-reinforced composite material (transversely isotropic material). I am currently working on a homogenization method for attaining the effective properties of fibre-reinforced composite materials. A lot of literature is available on how to compute the effective properties of composite material using homogenization.

**However, I would like to understand if the attained effective properties of composite material is a convex function or not?**

Considering only the linear (elastic) regime, how can one prove that composite's effective properties using the homogenization method are convex function or not?

I would be grateful if someone can help me to understand how I can approach the above problem or direct me to the relevant paper (if it exists).

Thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: Can you share more details or a reference for the homogenization method you are using? Since you want to know whether some function is convex, perhaps sharing the function you mean would be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Brandon.

The attached reference paper uses the asymptotic homogenization method to evaluate homogenized effective elasticity (i.e. stiffness) tensor ( Please refer to section 2.1 ).
Please let me know if I still lack the necessary details while asking my query?

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0045782520304059?via%3Dihub

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned (the OP has not logged in since a few days after asking it). It can be reopened if someone would like to provide an answer or the OP returns.